# PDFTeXify+preview in WinEdt 9.0

Tags: errors, winedt, texify

Until several hours ago, when I was clicking <kbd>Shift+Ctrl+P</kbd> in WinEdt 9.0, it did both the compilation and gave the preview of the pdf file.

However, now it only does the PDFTeXify processing. How can I return it back to the previous state?

The complete error is:

```
Command Line:   bibtex.exe "File1"
Startup Folder: E:\Folder1;File1

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9)
The top-level auxiliary file: File1.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file File1.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file File1.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file File1.aux
(There were 3 error messages)


Command Line:   texify.exe --pdf --tex-option=--interaction=errorstopmode --tex-option=--synctex=-1 "E:\Folder1;File1.tex"
Startup Folder: E:\Folder1;File1

pdflatex.exe: Invalid argument.
pdflatex.exe: Data: File1
texify: pdflatex.exe failed for some reason (see log file).


_____________________________________________________________________

 PDFTeXify Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 0   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: Also, This happens in all of my tex files in winedt, even in those I have not editted in days.

Comment: Which is the error you get?

Comment: @karlkoeller: The error is "pdflatex.exe failed for some reason (see log file)". But I can not access the log file, it is grayed

Comment: Can you add to the question the complete error you get in the console? There's a button 'Copy to Clipboard' in the console toolbar that helps.

Comment: @karlkoeller I have added the error message

Comment: You have a `;` in your folder name and this is causing the error.

Comment: WOW, This is absurd. I would've never found it on my own. Thanks A lot!!!!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have a semicolon (`;`) in your folder name and this is causing the error.

The path isn't recognised by pdflatex because it contains the semicolon.